# How to plot a bathymetry map in r with few colors and contours?

Tags: r, plot, mapping

I trying to create a bathymetry map of Papua New Guinea in R, but when I plot the map, it looks very busy with all the contour. I want to just make the land one color, and the water a second color, so the map looks very simple. I have attached my r code and the map created when I use it.

Best,
Shannon

```
library(marmap)
PNG_Map <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 144, lon2 = 158, lat1 = -14, lat2 = -8, 
resolution = 1) 
summary(PNG_Map)
library(zoom)

white <- ("white")
black <- ("black")

par(mfrow=c(1,1))

plot(PNG_Map, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, xlim=c(148.75,154), 
ylim=c(-14, -8.75), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", lty = c(1, 1, 1), lwd = 
c(0.6, 0.6, 1.2), bpal = list(c(0, max(PNG_Map), black), 
c(min(PNG_Map),0 , white)))
```

[image: Map of PNG]

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to create your map by calling the `plot.bathy()` function several times to draw what you want element by element. That way, you can add as many or as few isobaths as you want. Here are two examples based on your code (I've deleted unnecessary lines and arguments):

```
library(marmap)
PNG_Map <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 144, lon2 = 158, lat1 = -14, lat2 = -8, resolution = 1)     

# --- Black and white ---
plot(PNG_Map, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, xlim=c(148.75,154), ylim=c(-14, -8.75), n=100, lwd = 0.03, bpal = list(c(0, max(PNG_Map), grey(.3)), c(min(PNG_Map),0 , "white")))
plot(PNG_Map, deep=0, shallow=0, lwd = 0.6, add=T)  # Add coastline
plot(PNG_Map, deep=-200, shallow=-200, lwd = 0.4, drawlabels=T, add=T)  # Add -200m isobath
plot(PNG_Map, deep=-2000, shallow=-2000, lwd = 0.4, drawlabels=T, add=T)  # Add -2000m isobath


# --- With colors ---
# Creating color palettes
blues <- c("lightsteelblue4", "lightsteelblue3", "lightsteelblue2", "lightsteelblue1")
greys <- c(grey(0.6), grey(0.93), grey(0.99))

plot(PNG_Map, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, xlim=c(148.75,154), ylim=c(-14, -8.75), lwd = 0.03, bpal = list(c(0, max(PNG_Map), greys), c(min(PNG_Map),0 , blues)))
plot(PNG_Map, deep=0, shallow=0, lwd = 1, add=T)  # Add coastline
plot(PNG_Map, deep=-200, shallow=-200, lwd = 0.4, drawlabels=T, add=T)  # Add -200m isobath
plot(PNG_Map, deep=-2000, shallow=-2000, lwd = 0.4, drawlabels=T, add=T)  # Add -2000m isobath
```

[image]
[image]

The key arguments to play with when calling `plot.bathy()` for the first time are:

- `n=`: specifies a rough number of isobaths to plot
- `lwd=`: specifies the width of isobath lines

As suggested by lukeA, check `?plot.bathy` but also `vignette("marmap")` and `vignette("marmap-DataAnalysis")`. A whole lot of examples are presented there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try it like this:

```
pal1 <- list(
  c(min(PNG_Map), 0, "purple", "blue", "lightblue"),
  c(0, max(PNG_Map), "yellow", "brown"))
pal2 <- list(
  c(min(PNG_Map), 0, "blue"),
  c(0, max(PNG_Map), "yellow"))
plot_it <- function(pal, n, ...) {
  plot(PNG_Map, image=TRUE, land = TRUE, bpal = pal, n = n,
       xlim=c(148.75,154), ylim=c(-14, -8.75), ...)
}
par(mfrow = c(3, 1), mar = c(0,0,0,0), bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
plot_it(pal1, 1)
plot_it(pal2, 10)
plot_it(pal2, 10, deep=min(PNG_Map), shallow=0, step = 1000)
```

[image]

Also check `?plot.bathy` for the documentation.